# How to upload an image from URL

Tags: python, django

I've got 2 ways to upload an image. 1 is choosing an image from the user's files and the other is for uploading an image via URL.

**models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    imageURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    def download_file_from_url(self):
        print('DOWNLOAD') #prints "DOWNLOAD"
        # Stream the image from the url
        try:
            request = requests.get(self, stream=True)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            # TODO: log error here
            return None

        if request.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            # TODO: log error here
            return None

        # Create a temporary file
        lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

        # Read the streamed image in sections
        for block in request.iter_content(1024 * 8):

            # If no more file then stop
            if not block:
                break

            # Write image block to temporary file
            lf.write(block)
            return files.File(lf)
```

**html**

```
    <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image" /> <!--upload from file-->
    {{ form_post.imageURL|placeholder:"URL" }} <!--url upload-->
```

The image upload from files works fine, the user just clicks on the input and it chooses their file. However when the user decides to use the URL option instead..how do I get that URL string and make it the value for the `image` field?

views

```
    ...
    if form_post.is_valid():
        instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            if instance.imageURL:
                instance.image = Post.download_file_from_url(instance.imageURL)
                instance.save()
```

urls.py

```
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 compatible method:

```
import requests
import tempfile
from django.core import files

def download_file_from_url(url):
    # Stream the image from the url
    try:
        request = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # TODO: log error here
        return None

    if request.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        # TODO: log error here
        return None

    # Create a temporary file
    lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    # Read the streamed image in sections
    for block in request.iter_content(1024 * 8):

        # If no more file then stop
        if not block:
            break

        # Write image block to temporary file
        lf.write(block)

    return files.File(lf)
#Do this in your view
if self.url and not self.photo:
       self.photo = download_file_from_url(url)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm abit confused. Do I put `download_file_from_url()` in my model and then the last bit in my views?

Comment: @Zorgan Last bit should be in your views. The function is your call. Wherever you put it, you import it. If you are making download_file_from_url a class method, that is even more convenient.

Comment: Ok so i've put all the code in, and it successfully calls the function with no errors. However it doesn't save any image to the database. I've updated my edit if you wanna have a look.

Comment: Use ImageField instead of FileField and specify the upload_location. This is working for me. In your models you haven.t specified the upload location. So it does not upload it to your media.

Comment: I've specified the upload location in my `urls.py`, added in my edit. Why do I have to use ImageField and not FileField?

Comment: Using FIleField or image field doesn't matter. I don't think you quite get the concept of upload_location. You have specified which folder you media files will go to, but not where in the folder. You need to have initialized the file field like this `image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/location/')` so that your file goes in /media/uploads/location

Comment: I've specified where in my settings, added in edit. The `image` FileField uploads work for me and successfully save in the `media` folder, it's just the `imageURL` that doesn't.

Comment: are you doing `return files.File(lf)` in the end of function definition? Doesn't look like you are in your models.

Comment: Ok just added that in. I'm now getting a `SuspiciousFileOperation` error: `The joined path (/var/folders/t9/7y8mvz4s9fzylxh4k329640000gn/T/tmpeasda9bz) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/draft1/media)`. Any idea what this means?

Comment: try syncdb a.k.a migrate

Comment: This is working perfectly for me. You have some error in your code.

Comment: Yeah it probably is, I'll ask a new question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Zorgan Consider upvoting my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a string on a FileField. It needs to be a file. There is a workaround though. You need to download the file from the URL on your server and then save it to the database.

Here is a code that may help you:

```
class CachedImage(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_path, blank=True)

    def cache(self):
        """Store image locally if we have a URL"""

        if self.url and not self.photo:
            result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.url)
            self.photo.save(
                    os.path.basename(self.url),
                    File(open(result[0]))
                    )
            self.save()
```

Comment: Any idea how I can do that? I was looking at `urllib` which apparently worked for python2, but i'm using python3.

Comment: You can use https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

Comment: I've had a look though but still abit confused how to use `urlretrieve`..i've used it on the url string but from there i'm not sure how to save the image in the database. Could you have a look at my edit?

Comment: i edited my answer . Check and tell me if it works for you. mind to import the appropriate libraries
from django.core.files import File  
import urllib

Comment: Just tried your code, except I couldn't add `unique=True` as it was giving a `UNIQUE constraint failed` error. So I just used `max_length=255, blank=True, null=True` for `url`. However it doesn't even call the `cache()` function, I added a print statement in `cache()` and it doesn't print. Also I looked in my media folder after posting, and the image doesn't save in the database (`media` folder). Any idea?

Comment: first of all is the cache method inside the model? rather than that you need to set up a cache backend. plz check the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#caches